# How to copy from one image to another in a docker multistaged build?

Tags: php, docker, composer-php, docker-multi-stage-build

I want to copy the `vendor` folder from the composer image to another php image during a multistaged build.

My Dockerfile looks like this:

```
FROM composer
WORKDIR /tmp/composer-vendors/
COPY composer.lock composer.json ./
RUN composer install --ignore-platform-reqs
RUN pwd && ls

FROM php:7.3-fpm-alpine
WORKDIR /var/www/html
RUN pwd && ls
COPY --from=composer /tmp/composer-vendors/vendor ./vendor
CMD ["php-fpm"]
```

The `RUN pwd && ls` is only there to show that the files are indeed there.

Yet the `copy --from=composer` fails stating:

```
Step 9/10 : COPY --from=composer /tmp/composer-vendors/vendor ./vendor
COPY failed: stat /var/lib/docker/overlay2/c0cece8b4ffcc3ef3f6ed26c3131ae94813acffd5034b359c2ea6aed922f56ee/merged/tmp/composer-vendors/vendor: no such file or directory
```

What am I doing wrong?

---

My example `composer.json`:

```
{
  "name": "kopernikus/multistage-copy-issue",
  "require": {
    "nesbot/carbon": "^2.36"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to alias the image as otherwise docker uses the *base image* as provided by `composer` and not the image you built.

This means you need to change your FROM statement:

```
FROM composer as BUILDER
```

and reference your image:

```
COPY --from=BUILDER /tmp/composer-vendors/vendor ./vendor
```

---

The alias could be anything, I used `BUILDER` as an example. In fact, you could even reuse the name:

```
FROM composer AS composer
```

though that might lead to unexpected behavior if people are not expecting a modified image.